# Android Java Google API app crashing when allowing location access, but no problem when deny location...?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've tried this code from an UDEMY Course. Written same like him, he can access to location & also got a Toast while I cant opening app with allowed Location.
When allowing location, my app crashing.
But when deny I can see the map and not crashing anymore.

***My google map API also working good. also taken user Internet & Location Service.

MapsActivity.java:

```
package com.project.demo2map;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.project.demo2map.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, locationListener);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.
                    GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }else {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            } else {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.
                        GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }
}
```

CrashLog:

```
2021-10-25 14:59:29.003 25984-25984/com.project.demo2map D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-10-25 14:59:29.006 25984-25984/com.project.demo2map E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.project.demo2map, PID: 25984
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.location.LocationListener.onProviderDisabled(java.lang.String)"
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:365)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:275)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:291)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```

Comment: Logcat result pasted in the question sir.

Comment: override the method onProviderChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the onProviderChanged() method will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

check if any providers active.

```
if( locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) || 
locationManager .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    //start listener to requestUpdates ...
}else{
   //show message, no providers enabled.
}
```

Comment: showing no providers are enabled.

Comment: so you have to direct user to open one. For example user needs to open phone's location. Otherwise of course you can't get location info.